# PHP - Compare Date to current

Tags: php, date, compare

I have following in the database

```
$checktime = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM drafts WHERE page='sched'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
    if($row['posted'] = date('j-n-Y'))
    {
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

I'd like to compare this date against today's date. Please help me if everyone knows. thank you!

Comment: What goes wrong with the code you provided? (You are missing a closing `"` after your `SELECT` statement and using the wrong comparison operator `=`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition is wrong, it should have two equals to signs `==`

```
if($row['posted'] == date('j-n-Y'))
```

Please Note that one equal to sign is for assignment, it means that

```
$row['posted'] = date('j-n-Y')
```

The above code will assign the value of `date('j-n-Y')` into `$row['posted']`

And your assignment will do nothing but just return `true`, so every time it will go into the if condition block

where as the two equals to signs `==` are use for compression. so in your condition with double equals to, the code will only go into the if condition block when your `$row['posted']` is equal to `date('j-n-Y')`

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` functions are Officially deprecated (as of PHP 5.5. It's likely to be removed in the next major release.)

you need to have a look at this [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/829533)

Comment: thank you! HAHA! i forgot that. thanks. :)

Comment: So your problem is solved right ?