# Match Up Dates in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a website where many more campaigns added.
like double points campaigns in particular date range.

e.g.

```
Start Datetime - 2016-06-10 12:00
End Datetime - 2016-06-20 12:00
```

As current date in 2016-06-15, it should return **campaign is valid**

so campaign date setup as:
e.g.

```
Start Datetime - 2016-06-10 12:00
End Datetime - 2016-06-13 12:00
```

& then it returns as **campaign is invalid**.

I need to check whether particular campaign is valid or not on basis of start datetime, end datetime & current date time

How to compare both dates with current datetime in php ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Compare Date to current](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190939/php-compare-date-to-current)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isDateValid(DateTime $checkDate, DateTime $startDate, DateTime $endDate) {
    return ($checkDate > $startDate && $checkDate < $endDate) ? true : false;
}

$checkDate = new DateTime("2016-06-15");
$currentDate = new DateTime();//Current Date
$startDate = new DateTime("2016-06-10 12:00");
$endDate = new DateTime("2016-06-20 12:00");

$isDateValid =  isDateValid($checkDate, $startDate, $endDate);
if($isDateValid){
    echo "Campaign is valid";
}else{
    echo "Campaign is invalid";
}
```

> Refer : https://3v4l.org/dSUcP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$StartDatetime = strtotime("2016-06-10 12:00");
$EndDatetime   = strtotime("2016-06-20 12:00");

if(time() >= $StartDatetime && time() <= $EndDatetime)
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

Set your time zone as well. Hope this will work for you.....